# postgres SQLSTATE : PQresultErrorField returns NULL

Tags: c, database, postgresql

I am not able to get error details using the PQresultErrorField API after a query execution fails. Using PQerrorMessage on the connection gives the correct error (constraint violation xxx_pk etc etc) and PQresultStatus shows FATAL_ERROR.

However, when I use the API PQresultErrorField(result, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE)), I get a NULL result. Other field-codes also gives me null results. 
Does this API need to be compiled in ?

Postgres version is 9.2.1
Using libpq C library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to return NULL only when it's not applicable.
That simple test works for me:

```
  PGresult* res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT * FROM foobar");
  if (res) {
    if (PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_FATAL_ERROR) {
      char* p = PQresultErrorField(res, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE);
      if (p) {
        printf("sqlstate=%s\n", p?p:"null");
      }
    }
  }
```

Result:

> sqlstate=42P01